# Multiple grouping by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Lets say I have a table with business listings.

I'd like my result set to show in this order, but with one query:

First: Show the 5 most recently created listings in order of created_date.
Then: Show the rest of them but in random order.

My fields:

```
[BusinessName]
[Date_Created]
```

So if I had 100 businesses in the table, I want the list to show the 5 most recently created ones, and then show the rest but in random order.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: This sounds like a rather strange requirement. Why do you need everything beyond entry 5 to be sorted randomly?

Comment: @MitchWheat - My attempt is non-existent. Not out of laziness but rather I have no clue how to pull it off.

Comment: @lins314159 - I have a slider that shows business listings in random order each time the page loads. I was going to create a condition on the ones that were recently added and put a "NEW" flag on them somewhere...  But in fairness to the rest of the businesses I wanted them to load in random order each time the page loads. My prior solution was two separate queries, but it isn't flying real well with my overall goal using the one grid slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option A - Separating top 5 and the rest into two sub-queries and selecting them with `UNION`

```
WITH CTE_TOP5 AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 5  BusinessName, Date_Created, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE_CREATED DESC) RN FROM dbo.YourTable
    ORDER BY Date_Created DESC 
)
, CTE_REST AS 
(
    SELECT  BusinessName, Date_Created FROM dbo.YourTable
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT  BusinessName, Date_Created  FROM CTE_TOP5
)
,CTE_RESTRANDOM AS
(
    SELECT  BusinessName, Date_Created, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) + 5 RN FROM CTE_REST
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_TOP5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_RESTRANDOM
ORDER BY RN
```

Option B - `CASE` in `ORDER BY`

```
;WITH CTE_TOP5 AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 5 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE_CREATED DESC) RN FROM dbo.YourTable
    ORDER BY Date_Created DESC 
)
SELECT yt.*
FROM dbo.YourTable yt
LEFT JOIN CTE_TOP5 t5 ON yt.BusinessName = t5.BusinessName 
                     AND yt.Date_Created = t5.Date_Created
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t5.RN IS NOT NULL THEN t5.RN ELSE 6 END, NEWID()
```

Option C - Similar like B, but no CTE, ROW_NUMBERS and JOINS - whole logic goes in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable yt
ORDER BY CASE WHEN yt.Date_Created IN (SELECT TOP 5 yt2.Date_Created 
                                       FROM dbo.YourTable yt2 
                                       ORDER BY yt2.Date_Created DESC)
                 THEN yt.Date_Created 
              ELSE '1900-01-01' 
          END DESC, NEWID()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually found option C the easiest to implement. I appreciate your fast reply and help.. very much so!